# AngularJS - Disabling the PDF print/download bar when displaying PDF in browser. Converting PDF to Images?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I am exposing a PDF file in the browser like:

```
 //html
 <object ng-show="content" data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 550px;"></object>

 //angular controller
  $http.get('/api/,
    { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
    .success(function (response) {
        var file = new Blob([(response)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
    });
```

This works fine getting the Stream/Blob of the PDF back and exposing it in the browser, but I wish to not show the print/download/rotate bar that is shown at the top:

[image]

Any idea how this can be achieved? If I have to convert the PDF to a series of images is there a good way to do that from a BLOB form either on my client or server side?

Comment: hello have you found the solution for this?